# Volumes enclosed by $ \ln^2(x)+\ln^2(y)+\ln^2(z)+\cdots=1$

Tags: geometry, graphing-functions, volume, spheres

> Q: Find the volumes enclosed by $\ln^2(x)+\ln^2(y)+\ln^2(z)+\cdots=1$

I would like to find the volumes enclosed and then plot them to see their distribution as the dimension increases.

I've seen the plots of the volumes of hyper-spheres as the dimension increases and want to do the same for the equation above.

You might notice that the equation looks similar to the equation of a hyper-sphere but with logarithms. This is because this is the equation of a hyper-sphere in exponential space instead of regular $x,y,...$ space.

I think the area enclosed by $\ln^2(x)+\ln^2(y)=1$ can be written using a Bessel function.

Comment: It should be $\int_Be^{x_1+...+x_n}\mathrm{d}(x_1,...,x_n)$, where the integral is taken over the $n$-dimensional unit ball.

Comment: For $n=3$, the volume is $\left(\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt3}\right)^{3/2} I_{3/2}\!\left(\sqrt3\right)$

Comment: For $n=5$, the volume is $\left(\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt5}\right)^{5/2}I_{5/2}\!\left(\sqrt5\right)$

Comment: I was right about the Bessel function - thanks @robjohn!

Comment: I don't know if it can be written as a Bessel function for even dimensions, although it seems to work for odd dimensions. The example you gave was for $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $B_n$ be the interior of
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\log(x_k)^2=1\tag1
$$
Let $x_k=e^{u_k}$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{B_n}\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_{\|u\|\le1}e^{(1,1,\dots,1)\cdot u}\,\mathrm{d}u\tag{2a}\\
&=\int_{\|u\|\le1}e^{\sqrt{n}\,u_1}\,\mathrm{d}u\tag{2b}\\
&=\frac{\pi^{\frac{n-1}2}}{\Gamma\!\left(\frac{n+1}2\right)}\int_{-1}^1e^{\sqrt{n}\,t}\left(1-t^2\right)^{\frac{n-1}2}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{2c}\\
&=\frac{2\pi^{\frac{n-1}2}}{\Gamma\!\left(\frac{n+1}2\right)}\int_0^1\cosh\left(\sqrt{n}\,t\right)\left(1-t^2\right)^{\frac{n-1}2}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{2d}\\
&=\frac{2\pi^{\frac{n-1}2}}{\Gamma\!\left(\frac{n+1}2\right)}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_0^1\frac{n^kt^{2k}}{(2k)!}\left(1-t^2\right)^{\frac{n-1}2}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{2e}\\
&=\frac{\pi^{\frac{n-1}2}}{\Gamma\!\left(\frac{n+1}2\right)}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{n^k}{(2k)!}\int_0^1t^{k-\frac12}(1-t)^{\frac{n-1}2}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{2f}\\
&=\frac{\pi^{\frac{n-1}2}}{\Gamma\!\left(\frac{n+1}2\right)}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{n^k}{(2k)!}\frac{\Gamma\!\left(k+\frac12\right)\Gamma\!\left(\frac{n+1}2\right)}{\Gamma\!\left(k+\frac{n}2+1\right)}\tag{2g}\\
&=\frac{\pi^{\frac{n}2}}{\Gamma\!\left(\frac{n}2+1\right)}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{n^k}{(2k)!}\frac{\Gamma\!\left(k+\frac12\right)\Gamma\!\left(\frac{n}2+1\right)}{\Gamma\!\left(\frac12\right)\Gamma\!\left(k+\frac{n}2+1\right)}\tag{2h}\\
&=\frac{\pi^{\frac{n}2}}{\Gamma\!\left(\frac{n}2+1\right)}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{n^k}{(2k)!}\frac{(2k-1)!!\,\Gamma\!\left(\frac{n}2+1\right)}{2^k\,\Gamma\!\left(k+\frac{n}2+1\right)}\tag{2i}\\
&=\frac{\pi^{\frac{n}2}}{\Gamma\!\left(\frac{n}2+1\right)}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{n^k}{4^kk!}\frac{\Gamma\!\left(\frac{n}2+1\right)}{\Gamma\!\left(k+\frac{n}2+1\right)}\tag{2j}\\
&=\frac{\pi^{\frac{n}2}}{\Gamma\!\left(\frac{n}2+1\right)}\,\vphantom{F}_0F_1\!\left(;\frac n2+1;\frac n4\right)\tag{2k}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a):}$ $x_k=e^{u_k}$
$\text{(2b):}$ rotate coordinates
$\text{(2c):}$ integrate in slices where the area of a slice is $\dfrac{\pi^{\frac{n-1}2}}{\Gamma\!\left(\frac{n+1}2\right)}\left(1-t^2\right)^{\frac{n-1}2}$
$\text{(2d):}$ $e^x=\cosh(x)+\sinh(x)$
$\phantom{\text{(2d):}}$ the integral of $\sinh(x)$ over $[-1,0]$ is the the negative of that over $[0,1]$
$\phantom{\text{(2d):}}$ the integral of $\cosh(x)$ over $[-1,0]$ is the same as over $[0,1]$
$\text{(2e):}$ apply the series for $\cosh(x)$
$\text{(2f):}$ substitute $t\mapsto t^{1/2}$
$\text{(2g):}$ apply the [Beta integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)
$\text{(2h):}$ cancel $\Gamma\!\left(\frac{n}2+1\right)$ and multiply by $\frac{\sqrt\pi}{\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}2+1\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}2+1\right)}$
$\text{(2i):}$ $\frac{\Gamma\left(k+\frac12\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)}=\frac{(2k-1)!!}{2^k}$
$\text{(2j):}$ $(2k)!=2^kk!(2k-1)!!$
$\text{(2k):}$ write as a [generalized hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function)

Jack D'Aurizio's answer matches $\text{(2c)}$ except that $\dfrac{\pi^{\frac{n-1}2}}{\Gamma\!\left(\frac{n+1}2\right)}$ in $\text{(2c)}$ is replaced by $\dfrac{\pi^{\frac{n}2}}{\Gamma\!\left(\frac{n}2+1\right)}$.

The maximum occurs at $n=5$, but it is only $0.003717818$ greater than at $n=6$.

[image]

Here is the surface for $n=3$:

[image]

Its volume is
$$
\frac{4\pi}3\left(\cosh\left(\sqrt3\right)+\frac{\sinh\left(\sqrt3\right)}{\sqrt3}\right)\tag3
$$

Comment: You can [simplify](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=hypergeometric0F1regularized%28n%2F2%2B1%2Cn%2F4%29%2C0F1%28n%2F2%2B1%2Cn%2F4%29%2Fgamma%28n%2F2%2B1%29) the notation for ($2$k)

Comment: Does anyone other than Wolfram use the $\vphantom{F}_0\tilde F_1$ notation for regulartized hypergeometric functions? This does remove the division by the Gamma function, but is it worth adding another function?

Comment: The constant $\dfrac{\pi^{\frac{n}2}}{\Gamma\!\left(\frac{n}2+1\right)}=\Omega_n$ is the volume of the unit sphere in $n$-dimensions.

Comment: +1 for the animation. How did you create that animation?

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku Looks like Mathematica, so I'm guessing [`Animate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Animate.html) applied to a [3D contour plot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot3D.html) with a signature [`Texture`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Texture.html)

Comment: Actually, I applied [`Export`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html) to [`Show`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html) two [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) calls on two [`ParametricPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot3D.html) invocations. One of the `ParametricPlot3D` invocations uses a custom [`ColorFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html) that renders the [`Image`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Image.html) of the avatar.

Answer (score 3):

Letting $B_n$ denote $\{x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2\leq 1\}$ our integral equals
$$\int_{B_n}\exp\sum x_i\,d\mu = \int_{B_n}\exp(\sqrt{n} x_1)\,d\mu=\int_{-1}^{1}\exp(\sqrt{n}x)\frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(1+n/2)}(1-x^2)^{(n-1)/2}\,dx $$
which has a reasonably simple closed form for any odd $n$.
 Its maximum is at $n=4$, then we have a rapid decay towards zero:

[image]

Comment: Since you’re integrating $n-1$ dimensional slices, I believe the constant in your integral should be $$\frac{\pi^{\frac{n-1}2}}{\Gamma\!\left(\frac{n+1}2\right)}$$