# Predicting shape of regions defined by $f(x)^2+f(y)^2\le1$

Tags: graphing-functions, surfaces

For certain choices of elementary function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, the inequality

$$f(x)^2 + f(y)^2 \le 1$$

describes a region $D\subset\Bbb R^2$ that is bounded, connected, symmetric (i.e. containing at least one axis of symmetry, but not necessarily radially), and in some cases strongly resembles the unit disk. $D$ is the interior of what I think might be classified as a family of [superformulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superformula).

- $f(z)=z$ of course gives the unit disk itself
- $f(z)=z^n$ for $n\in \Bbb N$ traces out a [progressively rectangular disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse) as $n$ gets larger
- $f(z)=\sqrt[2n+1]{z}$ for $n\in\Bbb N$ draws out a progressively "pinched" astroid (another case shown in the same Wiki link)
- $f\in\left\{\sin^{-1},\sinh^{-1},\tan^{-1},\tanh^{-1}\right\}$, but not $f=\cos(\operatorname h)^{-1}$ nor any of these functions' "reciprocal" companions, each generate a pseudo-circular region
- $f=\log$ produces a rounded triangular region (the 2D case of the surface discussed in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3497651/volumes-enclosed-by-ln2x-ln2y-ln2z-cdots-1/))

[image]

I've played around with a few compositions of these functions (avoiding reciprocals or division), and some exotic combinations had preserved boundedness, though often lost connectedness, symmetry, and disk-similarity.

[image]

For the polynomial case, varying choices of coefficients and powers allow $D$ to be a disconnected region, which I assume is due to the nature of the poly's roots.

[image]

**Question:**

> Without the help of CAS or graphing utilities, are there any special properties of compound functions $f$ that can help predict the general shape of $D$?

By "predicting the general shape", I mean: can we answer definitively without unsheathing a graphing calculator,

- Is $D$ bounded?
- Is $D$ connected?
- Is $D$ symmetric?

The polynomial case with, say $\operatorname{deg}f\le4$, strikes me as the simplest, so I have no problem with an answer that focuses on only this scenario.

Comment: wait so you are asking questions that involve unit disk, but then use $z$ for a real argument ? That confused me a bit.

 Either way, one sufficient condition for connectedness would be the map $F = f^2(x) + f^2(y)$ is a homeomorphism, which can be investigated by applying the Implicit Function theorem with the Jacobian. 



I think the symmetry question needs to be defined in more detail. It's always going to be symmetric w.r.t to the $y = x$ line, but you might thinking of a family of symmetry like radial ?

Comment: @dezdichado Thanks for your comment! $f$ is a strictly real-valued function; I use $z$ as a placeholder. By "symmetry" I mean that $D$ possesses at least one line of symmetry. As you point out, $y=x$ seems to be common to most $f$. For example, the `Log` case is symmetric only about $y=x$; `ArcTan` has four lines of symmetry through the origin; $-z^2-3z-1$ also has four, but not all through the origin.